# Google Chrome Extension - Execute audio player page on background

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, background

I need to execute a page that contains an audio player when I click the extension I'm building. But when I click outside of it, the player stops. I need to keep it running.

I tried to use the "background" attribute on the manifest file, but I think it only works with javascript files.

Any sugestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a background page or an event page (according to a permanent or temporary need).

> http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html

You just have to provide a `page` attribute to the `background` property. As mentioned in the above page.